# Transferring specific data from one sheet to another and delete duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have an excel where I have two sheets, sheet "one" and sheet "two". In my 'test' excels sheet 1 has 4 columns from A to D. If columns A and B are same as the new row, macro deletes older row. On the sheet2 there is values for different numbers for column A. I need a macro what transfers these values to corresponding numbers of column A to column D. I hope I explain this clearly :) Here is an example of my 'test' excel.

```
     One             Two
   A  B  C  D      
1  2  2  2         2 = work
2  3  3  3         3 = fun
3  2  2  2
4  1  1  1

 After macro ----->

       One
    A  B  C  D
 1  3  3  3  fun
 2  2  2  2  work
 3  1  1  1
```

Now macro has deleted row 2 and transferred correct data to column D.

Here is what I have tried already: (The biggest problem is transferring data from sheet2 to sheet 1)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
lastrow = Worksheets("one").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

Worksheets("two").Cells(i, 1).Copy
erow = Worksheets("two").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("two, work").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("one").Cells(erow + 1, 5)

Worksheets("two").Cells(i, 2).Copy
Worksheets("two, fun").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("one").Cells(erow + 1, 5)

Next i

With Columns("A:B")
    .Sort key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("B1"),   Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess
    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlGuess
End With


End Sub
```

This is just a test excel, but in the actual there is over 2000 rows, so eventhough my macro doesnt work correctly, it is veeeery slow. I find this very hard, and I have no idea how to transfer data correctly to corresponding values. I would REALLY appreciate any help I get. THANK YOU! :)

Comment: Why not just copy all the data, remove duplicates and add a vlookup?

Comment: Your problem description it is not matching with your code. You are talking regarding 2 Excel Datasheets, and on your code you have: Worksheets("two"), Worksheets("two, work") and Worksheets("two, fun"). Could you upload some screenshots?

Comment: do you need to re-evalute `erow ` everytime you enter you loop?